# Fast return when search common prefix keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a company index

```
health status index               uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   company             KTngnM6ASD-_KdU0FFAWRA   1   0   88243299     29462913     24.7gb         24.7gb
```

because many company name has same prefix, e.g. Shanghai. So if you only search `Shanghai` it is very slow

Query from slowlog:

```json
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name": {
                  "query": "Shanghai",
                  "operator": "AND",
                  "prefix_length": 0,
                  "max_expansions": 50,
                  "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                  "lenient": false,
                  "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                  "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                  "boost": 1.0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "shortName": {
                  "query": "Shanghai",
                  "operator": "OR",
                  "prefix_length": 0,
                  "max_expansions": 50,
                  "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                  "lenient": false,
                  "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
                  "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                  "boost": 2.9
                }
              }
            },
            { "term": { "name.keyword": { "value": "Shanghai", "boost": 2.0 } } },
            { "match_phrase": { "name": { "query": "Shanghai", "slop": 0, "zero_terms_query": "NONE", "boost": 1.0 } } }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative": true,
          "minimum_should_match": "1",
          "boost": 1.0
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": { "match_all": { "boost": 1.0 } },
          "field_value_factor": { "field": "weight", "factor": 1.0, "missing": 0.0, "modifier": "none" }
        },
        {
          "filter": { "match_all": { "boost": 1.0 } },
          "field_value_factor": { "field": "viewCount", "factor": 1.0, "missing": 0.0, "modifier": "log1p" }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "sum",
      "max_boost": 3.4028235e38,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "profile": true
}
```

In normal situation user will search specific name, e.g. Alibaba , in this case the response time is not slow, but if user search common prefix e.g. Beijing Shanghai it will be slow.

Does exist some manner could implement this purpose that is if user search some common prefix,  just return the requested size docs which just contains the common prefix do not need score or something else work

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Is your goal to have a faster query or some kind of different type of logic to handle these?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas in short I want for common prefix keyword could ignore complicated score and sort work just return some started with keyword docs, if not common prefix keyword still follow normal query logic

Comment: Do you know these common prefixes in advance?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I could know some prefix keyword from slow log, but I want to dynamically to precess this logic, because prefix or suffix like Co Ltd could hit many docs e.g. total_hits[4012520+ hits] So I think if could base hits count to dynamically process if more than 10000 hits could be considered as prefix or suffix

Comment: It would not be possible within ES. You'd need to bake this logic into your application. But just to clarify, the issue is that your queries perform badly, that's it? What if you refactored your queries/indices so that all queries perform as good as others?